Logic App workflow run is marked as "Failed" because on action fails, even though dependent actions succeed
Our workflow having Multiple SMTP connectors to handle 429 errors. basically , if there is a failure in a connector redirection is based on status code to next SMTP connector.
The above logic helped us in achieve functionally but we notice any one failure of SMTP indicates the entire workflow as failure and that not the real case because it is getting successful in another SMTP connector. we want to make the workflow to success if any of the SMTP connector get successful. Let us know on that and attached a screen shot for your reference.
we want to make the workflow to success if any of the SMTP connector get successful. Let us know on that and attached a screen shot for your reference.

In order to mark the workflow success if any of the action gets successful, you can use Scope in your logic app.
Lets say I have a condition action which checks the status code and based on the status, it directs to the next flow. I have added Scope action after condition block which has below settings to mark the workflow success.

In this way you can add the scope block after any action for better error handing, also you can wrap the actions in scope block too.

References -
Logic Apps Error handling - configure run after settings | Serverless360 (turbo360.com).
